# Javascript: If then statement not working in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, if-statement

I'm building a personality-type quiz and having difficulty tailoring the results page as I'd like it to. The if statement, contained in the display_scenario function, isn't working. I want it to generate a different final message depending on the value of the countValue variable but it's not working. If you are able to help me understand why it's not working, I'd appreciate it.

The key pieces of code are below. It's also in place on Codepen: http://codepen.io/msummers40/pen/eZaePe

Essentially, the quiz:
- asks people a series of questions
- each answer has a numeric weight assigned to it
- this numeric weight is tallied in the countValue variable
- I want to use the countValue variable as a way to generate one of four final pages

I've tried to set up an if statement at the end of the quiz but it's just not working and I'm unsure of how to get this to work - it seems to be building the final view regardless of what's in the if statement.

If you are able to help, thank you.

```
<body>
<!-- QUIZ BEGINS -->
<div id="wrapper">
<h2 id="cyoaHeader">TITLE HERE<br><small>SUBHED</small></h2>
<div id="quizImage">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="prompt">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="options">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="buildingStatus">&nbsp;</div>   
</div>
<div id="addLinks">&nbsp;</div>
<!-- QUIZ ENDS -->

<script>

// JSON for quiz
// Contains the questions, images and variable to give answers weight/direction

var story = {
  intro: {
    prompt: 'You need to get up and out and get on with a big task - what song would propel you out of bed?',
    quizImage: '<img id="quizImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Semi-nude_woman_getting_out_of_bed_(rbm-QP301M8-1887-265a~5).jpg"><br />',
    options: [{
      name: 'Song 4',
      path: 'questionTwo',
      addition: 4
    }, {
      name: 'Song 3',
      path: 'questionTwo',
      addition: 2
    }, {
      name: 'Song 2',
      path: 'questionTwo',
      addition: 3
    }, {
      name: 'Song 1',
      path: 'questionTwo',
      addition: 1
    }]
  },

  questionTwo: {
    prompt: 'Sentence.<br/><br/>Question 2?',
    quizImage: '<img id="quizImage" src="http://www.allgifs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/pancake.gif">',
    options: [{
      name: 'A',
      path: 'result',
      addition: 4
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      path: 'result',
      addition: 3
    }, {
      name: 'C',
      path: 'result',
      addition: 2
    }, {
      name: 'D',
      path: 'result',
      addition: 1
    }]
  },

  result: {
    prompt: 'This is the default statement on the results page. I need to make it tailored to the countValue variable',
    quizImage: '<img id="quizImage" src="http://viralgifs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/cat_did_u_forget.gif">',
    options: [{
      name: 'FINAL CTA',
      path: 'intro',
      addition: 0
    }]
  }
};


//establishing counter for weighted answer
var countValue = 0;
console.log(countValue);
var additionInt = 0;
console.log(additionInt);


// Option is an object with properties {name and path objects, addition array}

function display_scenario(options) { //value passed had been chosen_options
  var option_name = options.name;
  var option_path = options.path;
  var additionInt = options.addition;
  countValue += additionInt;
  // countValue = (additionInt + countValue);
  console.log(additionInt);
  console.log(countValue);
  var scenario = story[option_path];

  // Clear the #prompt, #quizImage, #options, #addLinks, #buildingStatus divs before writing new ones in if statment below -- GROUP THESE IN A FUNCTION BEFORE GO LIVE
  jQuery('#prompt').empty();
  jQuery('#quizImage').empty();
  jQuery('#options').empty();
  jQuery('#addLinks').empty();
  jQuery('#buildingStatus').empty();

  // THIS IF ELSE STRUCTURE DOESN'T SEEM TO BE WORKING - I'M TRYING TO SET IT UP SO THAT IT DISPLAYS ONE OF FOUR OPTIONS, DEPENDING ON THE VALUE OF THE countValue VARIABLE. ATM ONLY THREE OPTIONS ARE IN PLACE; NONE ARE WORKING.
  // Create a <p> to display what the user has chosen if option_name is not null and append it to the #prompt <div>
  if (options.name != 'result') {
    jQuery('<p>').html('<i>You selected <b>' + option_name + '</b></i><br><p>And the running total is ' + countValue + '</p>').appendTo('#buildingStatus');
    // Append the scenario's prompt
    jQuery('<p>').html(scenario.prompt).appendTo('#prompt');
    // Appending an image
    jQuery('<p>').html(scenario.quizImage).appendTo('#quizImage');
    // Appending links in the addLinks div
    jQuery('<div>').html(scenario.addLinks).appendTo('#addLinks');
  } else if (options.name == 'result' && countValue<17) {
    jQuery('<p>').html('<i>Yay! This option worked. You selected <b>' + option_name + '</b></i><br><p>And the running total is ' + countValue + '</p>').appendTo('#buildingStatus');
    // Append the scenario's prompt
    jQuery('<p>').html(scenario.prompt).appendTo('#prompt');
    // Appending an image
    jQuery('<p>').html(scenario.quizImage).appendTo('#quizImage');
    // Appending links in the addLinks div
    jQuery('<div>').html(scenario.addLinks).appendTo('#addLinks');
  } else {  
    jQuery('<p>').html('<i>Yay! This option worked. You selected <b>' + option_name + '</b></i><br><p>And the running total is ' + countValue + '</p>').appendTo('#buildingStatus');
    // Append the scenario's prompt
    jQuery('<p>').html(scenario.prompt).appendTo('#prompt');
    // Appending an image
    jQuery('<p>').html(scenario.quizImage).appendTo('#quizImage');
    // Appending links in the addLinks div
    jQuery('<div>').html(scenario.addLinks).appendTo('#addLinks');
  };

// Append the options into the #options <div>
  // We want to loop through all the options and create buttons for each one. A regular for-loop would not suffice because adding a button is not asynchronous. We will create an asynchronous loop by using recursion
  function add_option_button(index) {
    if (index === scenario.options.length) {
      // Base case
      return;
    }

    var option = scenario.options[index];

    // Create a <button> for this option and append it to the #options <div>
    jQuery('<button>')
      .html(option.name)
      .click(function(e) {
        // This is an onclick handler function. It decides what to do after the user has clicked on the button.

        // First, prevent any default thing that the button is going to do, since we're specifying our own action for the button
        e.preventDefault();

        // We'll want to call display_scenario() with this option
        display_scenario(option);
      })
      .appendTo('#options');

    // Add the next option button
    add_option_button(index + 1);
  }
  add_option_button(0);
}

// This function waits until the document is ready
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // Start the quiz
  display_scenario({
    name: null,
    path: 'intro',
    addition: 0
  });
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's *really* not clear what you're asking, you need to include details about what you expect to happen and what is happening. However, I can say that `scenario` is not in scope of the `add_option_button()` function as it's declared inside `display_scenario()`

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan - apologies for the ambiguity. I edited the question to attempt to clarify the problem. It's essentially with the if statement in the display_scenario function. The statement isn't working and I'm unsure what the problem is. Re your comment, thanks for pointing that out - I'll revise with that in mind.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - the scope of that variable isn't the problem. It's the if statement in the display_scenario function. I expected it to overwrite the contents of the 'result' element in the JSON with the html contained in the if statement. I set up this if statement by checking whether the prompt value was equal to the 'result' element. If it's not equal to 'result', this performs well - it pulls fields from the JSON. But the rest of the if statement doesn't work. I thought it would check the name of the final view of the quiz and the value of countValue but it's not. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to recalculate the sum whenever the user changes something, apart from displaying the scenarios everytime. Split the `display_scenario` function into one to display the options, and into separate logic to sum up all options choosen.

Comment: Thanks @adder. That's a good idea but utlimately I want the function to send HTML to the various divs, like #quizImage #prompt and #options. I attempted to do that by way of an if statement. The reason for this is I want to use the countValue variable to determine the HTML that overwrites the various ids - that value will reflect a user's choices they've made through the quiz. Do you think that an if statement is the right approach? Would splitting this into two functions help with that? In advance, thank you!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ob1vo4cf/ well the option.name is always != 'result', since it is what is written on the button. For final step, it is "final CTA".

Comment: that's a huge help (and a huge facepalm for me). I made that change and got the if statement to work. Thank you!